# Use JavaScript to Insert HTML elements

Tags: javascript

I have a number of posts that are arranged like:

```
<h2>
<p class="paragraph">
<h2>
<p class="paragraph">...
```

I would like to insert an image (a decorative visual separator) after each paragraph, specifically those with the class "paragraph". As there are a lot of similar posts, I would like to automate things to save a lot of work, if possible. I have tried a number of things, such as:

```
function insertImg() {
   var i = 0;
   var p = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
   var n = p.length;
      while (i < n) {
        p[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<img src="/image.jpg">');
        i++;}
}
```

I have tried a number of variations, such as using querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName, but nothing seems to work.

Obviously, I don't really know what I'm doing and am just fumbling around. Is there a way to get this done?

```js
function insertImg() {
  var i = 0;
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
  var n = p.length;
  while (i < n) {
    p[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<img src="/image.jpg">');
    i++;
  }
}
insertImg();
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p class="paragraph">Post</p>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p class="paragraph">Post</p>
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/3x9jgrsb/).  In what way does your code not work as expected?  Is your actual HTML valid, or is what you show here your actual HTML?  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable stack snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I added a snippet, showing your code is working. Are you seeing something different?

Answer (score 0):

If your script executes before (dynamic) content is added to your page, then
it will not do the job for that content.

You can use CSS for that. No JavaScript needed:

```css
.paragraph:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://duckduckgo.com/assets/icons/design.svg);
    background-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p class="paragraph">Post</p>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p class="paragraph">Post</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Not sure what went wrong before, but I deleted the code and re wrote it from scratch and now it works!